# Как импользовать правильно append jQuery / js

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

у меня вопрос по `$(this).append("");`

можно вместо такого кода

```js
$(this).append("<div class='wrapper'><button>start</button></div>");
```

использовать так

```js
$(this).append("

<div class='wrapper'>
   <button>start</button>
</div>

");
```

так как большой код например карточки выглядит не очень разборчево , спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Поищите: `ES6 строки`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> можно ли использовать так

Можно. Это вообще дело вкуса. Но также, конечно, и вопрос читабельности. Да, в таком стиле читабельность возрастёт, если код большой. Ещё больше в таком случае рекомендую такой подход:

```
let html =`
<div class='wrapper'>
   <button>start</button>
</div>`;

$(this).append(html);
```

тогда будет ещё чище.

К тому же, я использовал **обратные кавычки**, что позволит вставлять в строку переменные, без всякой конкатенации.

---

В целом рекомендую почитать "Роберт Мартин - Чистый код". Там освещены разные подходы и проблемы, в т.ч. с читаемостью.

Comment: спасибо большое , а какой синтаксис на переменые ?

Comment: Не понял вопроса

Comment: ну тоесть переменые можно вставлять так - ` frame is - {id}`  ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals